# Postgres: insert multiple rows on conflict update not working

Tags: postgresql, upsert

I am trying to insert multiple rows into a table, and, in case of conflict, simply update them. What am I doing wrong?

```
insert into segments(id, departure_hour) 
values 
    (1153, 2), 
    (1156, 4), 
    (1154, 2) 
on conflict do update set 
    departure_hour = c.departure_hour 
from (values 
    (1153, 2), 
    (1156, 4), 
    (1154, 2)) 
as c(id, departure_hour)
    where c.id = segments.id
```

As requested, here is my table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE segments (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    route_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES routes(id),
    origin_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES stops(id),
    destination_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES stops(id),
    price integer DEFAULT 0,
    departure_day integer NOT NULL,
    departure_hour integer NOT NULL,
    departure_minute integer NOT NULL,
    arrival_day integer NOT NULL,
    arrival_hour integer NOT NULL,
    arrival_minute integer NOT NULL,
    hidden boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    deleted boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    CONSTRAINT unique_origin_destination_per_route UNIQUE (route_id, origin_id, destination_id)
);
```

And here is my error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from"
LINE 1: ...pdate set       departure_hour = c.departure_hour from (valu...
```

Comment: For starters, your insert only specifies one target column, but your are giving values for two columns.  You might want to add the table definition for `segments` to your question.

Comment: What is your error?  I can see that your column declaration before `values` is missing a column (you specify only `departure_hour`, but you have 2 columns to update (`1153` and `2`, for example)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen you are right, but apparently changing the number of target columns gives the same error, so it means that there is something wrong even before getting there. Added the target column anyway.

Comment: @richyen added the error

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You don't need the `from` part in order to be able to reference the values to update.

```
insert into segments(id, departure_hour) 
values 
    (1153, 2), 
    (1156, 4), 
    (1154, 2) 
on conflict do update set 
    departure_hour = excluded.departure_hour;
```